# <Img src="logo.png"> not working in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making a site in mvc-5. I copied my logo.png picture to Views/Shared folder (same as _Layout.cshtml) and the only thing i see on my site is the default-non-working-photo icon.

```html
<img src="logo.png">
```

Comment: I thought that was a bad idea, but i wanted to try it the easiest way.
IT works this way! Thank You. But why didn't it work earlier?

Comment: Thanks again :).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i would recommend submitting your solution as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files (asssets (css files, fonts, etc) and javascript files) should not be mixed with MVC folders/files. Common reasons are opinionated and, since ASP.NET MVC is an opinionated framework, you have to make some changes for that to work, and I would advise against that.

The easiest way for this to work is to use the `Content` and `Scripts` folder that are already provided by the ASP.NET MVC templates.

Comment: Just want to say that there is only Scripts folder, no Styles folder in default template. Main Site.css file is in default Content folder - maybe here?

Comment: @ITmustBE Ooops, it's been some time since I've used MVC5. Yes, I meant content, fixed!

Answer (score -1):

Image paths (and other paths as well; javascript, css, etc.) need to be relative to the root of the site. So you need to set it as follows: `src="~/Views/Shared/logo.png"`

Comment: The Views folder will not be copied at all if view compilation is turned on. This is a terrible idea. There are specific folder for these assets

Comment: @Camilo that was not what the question was. And view compilation is turned off by default?!